# Flex Box Menu Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Been researching and adjusting the following code, but aligning the text with even spacing is eluding me.  I am able to accomplish this easily with a table element, but I want to master Flex Box methods.  Any help appreciated.

Screen Shot of text-alignment issue:

[image: Link to Text-alignment Screen Shot]

```css
#navbar-menu-button-mobile,
#navbar-container-mobile {
 display: flex !important;
}
/* === Navigation Drop-down Menu === */
#navbar-container-mobile {
 margin-top: 74px;
 padding: 0 1%;
 background: white;
}

.navbar-menu-item-mobile {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="navbar-container-mobile" class="container">
 <div id="navbar-collapse-mobile" class="collapse w-100">
  <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <div class="fa fa-calendar"></div><div class="pr-2"></div><div>Calendar</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <div class="fa fa-compass"></div><div class="pr-2"></div><div>Locations</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <div class="fa fa-heartbeat"></div><div class="pr-2"></div><div>Physicians</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <div class="fa fa-random"></div><div class="pr-2"></div><div>Trades</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <div class="fa fa-user"></div><div class="pr-2"></div><div>Personal</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <div class="fa fa-cog"></div><div class="pr-2"></div><div>Settings</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <div class="fa fa-sign-out"></div><div class="pr-2"></div><div>Sign Out</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example below assuming that you're using FontAweosme **v4**, Please follow this **Markup**:

```html
<div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
   <i class="menu icons"></i>
   <div>Menu label</div>
</div>
```

And you need to set **width**, **margin** to the icons:

```css
.navbar-menu-item-mobile .fa {
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
#navbar-menu-button-mobile,
#navbar-container-mobile {
  display: flex !important;
}

/* Add this */
.navbar-menu-item-mobile .fa {
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* === Navigation Drop-down Menu === */

#navbar-container-mobile {
  margin-top: 74px;
  padding: 0 1%;
  background: white;
}

.navbar-menu-item-mobile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="navbar-container-mobile" class="container">
  <!-- Removed collapse class for testing -->
  <div id="navbar-collapse-mobile" class="w-100">
    <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      <div>Calendar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
      <i class="fa fa-compass"></i>
      <div>Locations</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
      <i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i>
      <div>Physicians</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
      <i class="fa fa-random"></i>
      <div>Trades</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      <div>Personal</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
      <div class="fa fa-cog"></div>
      <div>Settings</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <div class="navbar-menu-item-mobile">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out "></i>
      <div>Sign Out</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a `min-width` to your icons